# uninitialized constant RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I use own gem

```
class Periscoper

class Client
  include HTTParty
  attr_reader :secret, :key, :id, :username, :display_name, :cookie

  base_uri 'https://api.periscope.tv/api/v2'
  format :json

  def initialize (key = nil, secret = nil)
    p login(key, secret) if (secret && key)
  end

  ....

end
end
```

When in controller I do follow:

```
periscope = Periscoper::Client.new(twitter.token, twitter.secret)
```

I get this:

> uninitialized constant SessionsController::Periscoper

Comment: can you give more details about what you did exactly when you say you used your own gem? As in you included "Periscoper" in the gemfile, and this file lives in `lib/periscoper.rb` in your gem? It looks like it's not loading correctly. Normally you don't have inner classes in ruby unless you are trying to encapsulate that inner class within the outer class. You would have modules on the outside or inside.

Answer (score 1):

```
periscope = ::Periscoper::Client.new(twitter.token, twitter.secret)
```

will most likely solve the issue.